# knitr: how to use child .Rnw docs with (relative) figure paths?

Tags: r, knitr

I have a parent and a child `Rnw` document. The child doc is located in the subfolder `children`, i.e.

```
+-- parent.Rnw
+-- children
    +-- child.Rnw
    +-- figure
         +-- test.pdf
```

Now I want to create the (margin) figure `test.pdf` from inside the child doc using the `pdf` function and place it in the folder `figure` inside the `children` folder (i.e. the local `figure` folder for `child.Rnw`).

**parent.Rnw**

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
I am the parent
<<child, child='children/child.Rnw'>>=
@
\end{document}
```

**child.Rnw**

```
<<parent, echo=FALSE, cache=FALSE>>=
knitr::set_parent("../parent.Rnw")
@

I am the child doc.

<<>>=
pdf("figure/test.pdf")
plot(1:10)
dev.off()
@

\marginpar{ \includegraphics[width=\marginparwidth]{figure/test.pdf} }
```

When compiling the `child.Rnw` everything works fine. The path to `figure/test.pdf` is correct for the child doc but not when compiling the parent doc. Then it would have to be `children/figure/test.pdf`.

**Question:** How can I have a correct path for the compilation of the child **AND** the parent doc?

Comment: Paths in child documents have been a nightmare for me, and I do not think I will ever have the time or courage to fix them (or perhaps it is just impossible to fix them because one has to consider both LaTeX and R). What I'd recommend is to put everything in a flat structure, i.e. parents and children in the same directory, and avoid nested directories.

Comment: @Yihui, is there a way that knitr can know during comilation if the document currently compiled is a child doc or not? I.e. from inside the child doc, is there a way for R to see if the if this is a child doc? If so, I will try to generate the path using a knitr chunk depending if the doc is a child or not.

Comment: Yes, there is an internal function `knitr:::child_mode()`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For me the following solution is suitable:
At the top of the child doc, I define a function that adjusts a relative path depending on whether the doc is run as a child or not:

```
# rp: a relative path
adjust_path <- function(path_to_child_folder, rp) 
{ 
  is.child <- knitr:::child_mode()
  function(rp) 
  {
    if (is.child)
      rp <- file.path(path_to_child_folder, rp)
    rp
  }  
}
```

Now, we supply the *from-the-parent-to-the-child-doc* path to the function `adjust_path`.

```
ap <- adjust_path("children")
```

The function returns a new function which can be used to adjust a relative path in a child doc. Now we can write

```
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{\Sexpr{ap("figure/test.pdf")}}
```

and the path will be correct if run as a child or standalone document.