# Include external Rmd file into another one in Blogdown

Tags: r, rstudio, r-markdown, blogdown

I am using blogdown to create content for the web. Often, I need to include some chunk of content coming from an `.Rmd` snipped (markdown + R computation).

#### Context

For example, I have this common content in `common.Rmd`:

````
The **correlation** between the terms of topic `A` and topic `B` is as follows:

    ```{r}
    kendall.tau(x,y)
    ```

Some more text here...
````

And then I have file `content1.Rmd`:

```
The two data sets are similar to topic `A` and `B`:

<reference 'common.Rmd' here>

Bla bla...
```

#### Question

How do I *include* `.Rmd` files so that their output is placed exactly where I want in another `.Rmd` file?

Comment: Have you tried child? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36558273/is-there-a-way-to-include-child-rmd-files-from-a-different-directory

Comment: Seems very related, I am trying it thanks

Comment: @PoGibas: Please post it as an answer, it worked :)

Comment: I wrote a function `source_rmd_chunks()` https://gist.github.com/brshallo/e963b9dca5e4e1ab12ec6348b135362e that handles just the R content part (though not the markdown stuff).